# LibGDX - Managing and starting new levels

Tags: libgdx, levels, tiled

I have a Manic Miner style game where you need to collect all the items from a screen before you can advance to the next screen.

I have a screen class called "PlayScreen" wich starts out by loading a tiled map called "Level1.tmx", and contains the render and update loop.

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {
    ...
}
```

This screen is loaded by my main Game class, by calling SetScreen

```
setScreen(new PlayScreen(this));
```

So inside my PlayScreen, what is the correct way to restart the game but with a different level? I know I can pass through a new level number to get it to load a new tiled map, but this usually crashes.

Do I need to dispose of the screen and reload it again. I cannot find much information about this. Most LibGDX tutorials only cover a single screen or level, or have a menu screen in between. I just want to switch to the next level or room on demand, but cannot get it working.

Has anyone done this before - can you recommend a good way of doing this?

Regards

James

Comment: Can you please give more information about the crashes you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

The `Screen` framework is designed so that you can change to another screen at any time. Your described method of doing do is correct-- by adding a parameter to your `PlayScreen` constructor

```
game.setScreen(new PlayScreen(this,levelNum));
```

The crash that you get when doing this is a different problem and you'll have to figure out where the crash is actually stemming from.

You should call `dispose()` on your `Screens` when you are done with them. In the example on the [libgdx wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Extending-the-simple-game) they dispose of the screen right as they set the screen to another screen. So in your `PlayScreen` class you could have a restart method like this:

```
public void restart(int levelNum){
    game.setScreen(new PlayScreen(this,levelNum));
    this.dispose();
}
```

Just be sure that your `Screen's` `dispose()` method doesn't dispose any assets shared between screens. Shared assets should be passed into the screens and should be disposed at a later time, most likely when the game exits.

Comment: The `dispose()` in `Game` can be used to clear the shared items.